# Update page content on option selection

Tags: php, html

I was wondering what is the best method to achieve this.
I have a `<select>` with different options.

I need the page content to update itself depending on what option I selected.
(If option one with the `id = "1"` has been selected, the page will update to show the correct informations (retrieved from a mysql database when selecting the option).

I do a lot of PHP in my pages.
I can't figure out the best method/langage to use to do that. It doesn't seem to be adequate to use PHP for this.

Comment: You will need to use AJAX

Comment: well it also depends upon the amount of content that is fetched and displayed, if it's more then you can use ajax call to fetch n display the data based upon selection, but if it's less then you can fetch all data in one go, arrange them in divs and show/hide divs based on selections.

Answer (score 0):

For a PHP developer it would be best to use javascript/JQuery

```
<select id="changing">
    ...
</select>

<script>
    var database_json = ["Hello!"];
    $("#changing").on("change", function(){
         $("body").html(database_json[$("#changing").val()]);
    });
</script>
```

Similar Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cnn8azqu/

More info on: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Or if you want something better I would recoment Vue.js https://vuejs.org/ or Angular https://angularjs.org/